# display automatically turns to perspective when I move the view

Tags: 3d-view

whenever I manually move the view with the most blender automatically switches from ortho to perspective mode.

how do I stop it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the *Preferences > Navigation > Orbit & Pan*, disable the *Auto Perspective* option:

[image]